# Dismiss popover using alertView

Tags: ipad, uialertview, uipopovercontroller, page-refresh

I am attempting to

- Dismiss a popover using an alertView and
- Refresh the screen so that I cannot link to the popover screen again.  Here is my code, please help me figure this out:

---

PasswordViewController.h

```
@protocol PopoverDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)didClickButton;
@end

@interface PasswordViewController
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<PopoverDelegate> delegate;
```

---

PasswordViewController.m

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(passwordTest == 1 && buttonIndex == 0){
        [self.delegate didClickButton];
    }
}
```

---

SecondViewController.h

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate, PopoverDelegate>
```

SecondViewController.m

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PasswordViewController delegate

-(void)didClickButton {
    if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
        [self popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:popoverController];
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
//Here, how should I refresh the screen?
        }
    }
```

---

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIPopoverController delegate

-(void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover {
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    popoverController.delegate = nil;
}
```